# dataset datetime format problem

Tags: c#, dataset

I am having a problem with datetime format in a dataset.

In the database date format is:10/5/2009 10:10:10

but i get an error:FormatException, when attempting to fill the DataSet:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM teklif"; 
c.db = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, c.con); 
c.db.Fill(ds);  // Error Here...
dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: More info is needed.  Is the date in the database stored as an actual datetime data type, or is it stored as a char/varchar, and you're trying to convert?  Can you post your code for where this error is occurring?  If it's not in code, can you type up the steps to reproduce?

Comment: Post some code.  You haven't supplied enough information for anyone to understand what the problem is.

Comment: by the way i get ann error when i load data in table to datset

Comment: When are you getting this error? When you try to populate the Dataset via a [Data|Table]Adapter, or when you try to access an individual column on a row?

Comment: string query = "SELECT * FROM teklif";

            c.db = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, c.con);
            
            c.db.Fill(ds);
            dt = ds.Tables[0];

Comment: I assume this is a strongly typed dataset. Are you sure the column is specified as a DateTime in the .xsd file?

Comment: David Stratton date field is in the format of datetime

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that you are not initializing the adapter right.

```
 MySQLiteConn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + fileName +
                    "; Compress = TRUE;");
SQLiteCommand cmd = MySQLiteConn.CreateCommand();


            SQLiteDataAdapter dr = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter;
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM teklif";
                adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
                dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);                    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Retrieval of Table Failed. " + ex.Message);
                return -1;
            }
```

If that fails then make sure that is the correct table name in your sqlite database.

Comment: This is supposed to be cleaner?